# Cursor is giving error while accessing data from User Dictionary in Android?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-cursor

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    // For the SimpleCursorAdapter to match the UserDictionary columns to layout items.
    private static final String[] COLUMNS_TO_BE_BOUND = new String[]{
            UserDictionary.Words.WORD,
            UserDictionary.Words.FREQUENCY
    };

    private static final int[] LAYOUT_ITEMS_TO_FILL = new int[]{
            android.R.id.text1,
            android.R.id.text2
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get the TextView which will be populated with the Dictionary ContentProvider data.
        ListView dictListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dictionary_list_view);

        //TextView dictTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dictionary_text_view);
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {

            // Get the ContentResolver which will send a message to the ContentProvider.
            ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();

            // Get a Cursor containing all of the rows in the Words table.
            cursor = resolver.query(UserDictionary.Words.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

            SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
                    cursor,
                    COLUMNS_TO_BE_BOUND,
                    LAYOUT_ITEMS_TO_FILL,
                    0
            );

            dictListView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.getMessage();
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }

    }

}
```

/*
If I not close the cusor then Memory leakage will occur. But it was not shown by the compiler!
I want to know what is exactly happening here?
Thanks in advance!
*/

Comment: you dont close cursors in an adapter until you are done using them

Answer (score 0):

When we open a cursor it has to be closed, or else there will be memory leak in the system global area.
A memory leak occurs when a program allocates memory for a data structure and then never releases that memory and does not reuse that memory. The next time the program needs the data structure, it allocates more memory again. Over time, the available memory appears to be shrinking and this is called a "memory leak." Memory leaks are overcome by ensuring the memory allocated for a data structure is deallocated when you are done using that data structure